# Domino Server 9.0.1 FP3 crashs when JAVA getAllEntries method (of the View class) follows a call to the FTSearch method

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I have an `XPage` application which is running on a `Domino Server 8.5.3 FP6`without any `FTSearch problems`.

Since a couple of weeks I am working on the migration to `Domino Server 9.0.1 FP3`.

---

Now it seems we have to deal with this [**bug**](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21229431)

**Remember:** We have no troubles on `Domino Server 8.5.3 FP6`!

In the above IBM technote you can find a paragraph *Resolving the Problem*
that decribes a workaround running the FTSearch on the ViewEntryCollection instead of the View Object

Example (Domino Server 9.0.1 crashs):

```
var nview:NotesView = database.getView("luDocumentsDownloadsHistory");
nview.FTSearch("[Downloader] = Homer Simpson/ncdev");

var col:NotesViewEntryCollection = nview.getAllEntries();

var viewEntry:NotesViewEntry = col.getFirstEntry();

while (viewEntry != null) {
    var tmpEntry:NotesViewEntry = col.getNextEntry();
    viewEntry.recycle();
    viewEntry = tmpEntry;
}
```

Example (with Workaround no crash):

```
var nview:NotesView = database.getView("luDocumentsDownloadsHistory");

var col:NotesViewEntryCollection = nview.getAllEntries();
col.FTSearch("[Downloader] = Homer Simpson/ncdev");

var viewEntry:NotesViewEntry = col.getFirstEntry();

while (viewEntry != null) {
    var tmpEntry:NotesViewEntry = col.getNextEntry();
    viewEntry.recycle();
    viewEntry = tmpEntry;
}
```

---

However, this workaround isn't working for me, because I have to work with `<xp:dominoView var="viewData" search="[FieldName] = FieldValue">` using the search-Attribute. Therefore it is not possible for me to move the FTSearch call from the View to the ViewEntryCollection.

Any idea why this problem **comes up** with Domino 9.0.1 FP3?

Comment: I would try to add a nview.clear at the third line if you don't get a crash then. the problem is probably that all entries tries to fetch everything and doesn't take in consideration that the view is filtered. I would create a support issue with IBM about this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I add a `niew.clear` then the server dosn't crash but I get all entries in the `ViewEntryCollection` and not a filtered result.

Comment: @Georg, are you certain you are seeing another occurrence of SPR# MMQN6L7KJ5?  Have you compared your NSD with the stack trace in the technote?  Even if it looks like the same problem, I second Fredrik's suggestion to report it to IBM.  Each new report adds "weight" to the SPR and makes it more likely it will get fixed in an upcoming fix pack.

Comment: @Dave: First of all thanks for your answer. Just now, I have compared the NSD stack trace of my Domino Server with the 8.0.x stack trace in the technote. I can’t say exactly, whether both of them are nearly equal, but you can find many equal lines...

Comment: @Dave: 
**Here the equal lines:**
thread 71/84: [ nserver:  0488:  19e8] FATAL THREAD (Panic)
ntdll.ZwWaitForSingleObject
KERNELBASE.WaitForSingleObjectEx
nnotes.OSRunExternalScript
nnotes.FRTerminateWindowsResources
nnotes.OSFaultCleanupExt
nnotes.OSFaultCleanup
nnotes.OSNTUnhandledExceptionFilter
nnotes.Panic

Comment: I think those few lines are fairly common for a crash stack trace.  So this could be a different problem.  It would be best to report it to IBM and include the NSD log.

Comment: We have reported the bug to IBM. Thanks for your investigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## BUG Fixed, Domino Server doesn't crash anymore

We have got the following message with a link to a testfix `901FP3HF154_W64.exe` from IBM which works perfect:

ftp://ftp.ecurep.ibm.com/fromibm/pmr/16502,SGC,618/901FP3HF154_W64.exe

Thanks once more to the guys of IBM Ireland, they have worked in a very professional way to help us with our problem :)

Answer (score 2):

Technote says also:

> The issue is limited to cases where the search returns more than approximately 16,300 documents (the specific value may vary). The issue does not occur if the method's MaxDoc parameter or the Notes.ini FT_Max_Search_Results are used to limit the value to a value less than 16,300 documents.

Set `FT_Max_Search_Results` and `TEMP_INDEX_MAX_DOC` to some reasonable value, for example 500. Although, it says anything below 16,300 is safe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I know this limtitation, but the problem is, I have to deal with more than 16300 documents. On the Domino Server 8.5.3 I have FTSearch results with more than 50000 documents without any problems. In this case the notes.ini entry `FT_Max_Search_Results` is set to `0`

Answer (score 0):

## Status Report

First of all I would like to say, that we have reported our problem to IBM.

**IBM's last questions for further investigations:**

> 1. Will you be kind and let me know if you are using in your applications, the LSI_INFO functions?
> 2. Can you confirm if the issue was still occurring in Domino 853 but not occurring in Domino 853FP6
>
> The reason I am asking this is that the main suspect in this case
> seems to be SPR # RGAU8ZRLKH:  Xpages: Domino Server Crashing When
> Hitting Last Page Of A Largeview And Param
> Ft_max_search_results=99999999
>
> If this is confirmed, we may request an hotfix from our development.

**Here our findings/ answers:**

1. Calling unsupported LotusScript function `LSI_Info` may cause a crash. But we don't use LSI_INFO functions in our application.
2. We have uninstalled FP6 on our Domino Server 8.5.3 and made some tests without any problems. Therefore we can't confirm that this issue will still occure on Domino 8.5.3. It works very well on both Domino Server 8.5.3 installations (with and without FP6).

*Environment details:*

- Domino Server 8.5.3 64 Bit
- Windows 64 Bit
- No hotfixes installed

---

Thanks to the guys of IBM Ireland, they are working very well to identify the bug.